# Is the description of the index set appearing in the referenced text an error?

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebra-precalculus, index-notation

The following appears in [BBFSK](https://archive.org/stream/MyStuff38/Behnke%2C%20Bachmann%2C%20Fladt%20%26%20Suss%20%5BEds.%5D%20-%20Fundamentals%20of%20Mathematics%20Vol.1%2C%20The%20Real%20Number%20System%20and%20Algebra%5BMIT%20Press%2C%20555p%5D), page 118 equations (41) and (41').

> $$\underset{i=1}{\overset{n}{\sum}}a_{i}\underset{k=1}{\overset{m}{\sum}}b_{k}=\underset{1\le k\le m}{\sum_{1\le i\le n}}a_{i}b_{k}$$

> By complete induction we readily obtain from [the previous equation]

> $$\overset{m}{\prod_{i=1}}\sum_{k=1}^{n_{i}}a_{i,k}=\underset{(i=1,\ldots,m)}{\sum_{1\leq k_{i}\leq n_{i}}}\prod_{i=1}^{m}a_{i,k_{i}};$$

> where the index set for the summation on the right-hand side is the set of m-tuples $\left(k_{1},\ldots,k_{m}\right)$ with $1\leq k_{i}\leq n_{i}\left(i=1,\ldots,m\right).$

I can't make sense of the given description of the index set.  It seems it should be the set of $n_{i}-tuples,$ $\left\{1,\dots,n_{i}\right\}$ with $1\le{i}\le{m}$.  That is the index set is a "jagged array" of $m$ rows.  Each $i^{th}$ row is $\left\{1,\dots,n_{i}\right\}$,  and $n_{i}$ could be any natural number. Am I missing something, or is the description given in the book inconsistent with the expression under discussion?  Is my description correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It helps to look at a concrete example, for example, taking $m=2$, $n_1=2$, and $n_2=3$ we get
\begin{align}
(a_{1,1}+a_{1,2})(a_{2,1}+a_{2,2}+a_{2,3}) &= a_{1,1}a_{2,1} + a_{1,1}a_{2,2} + a_{1,1}a_{2,3} \\
 &\qquad + a_{2,1}a_{2,1} + a_{2,1}a_{2,2} + a_{2,1}a_{2,3}
\tag{1}
\end{align}
here we can see that all the terms on the right hand side are $2$-fold products. In your equation, an $m$-tuple $(k_1,\dots,k_m)$ corresponds to the term $\prod_{i=1}^ma_{i,k_i}$, so in $(1)$ the terms correspond to the $2$-tuples $(1,1)$, $(1,2)$, $(1,3)$, $(2,1)$, $(2,2)$, $(2,3)$ in order. This enumerates *all* $2$-tuples $(k_1,k_2)$ where $1\leq k_1\leq2$ and $1\leq k_2\leq3$.

In general, if you expand a product of sums
$$
\prod_{i=1}^m\sum_{k=1}^{n_i}a_{i,k} \tag{2}
$$
distributivity of multiplication over addition will combine every $a_{1,k_1}$ with every possible choice of $a_{2,k_2}$, then every possible choice of $a_{3,k_3}$, and so on until $a_{m,k_m}$. (This is an English interpretation of the induction you quoted in your question.) In particular, every summand in the full expansion of $(2)$ consists of $m$ factors. This is why the sum on the right hand side indexes only over $m$-tuples rather than a "jagged array" of $m$ rows.
Since the distributivity makes every possible combination as described above, we have to see every possible $\prod_{i=1}^ma_{i,k_i}$ exactly once. Since each $k_i$ ranges from $1$ to $n_i$, this provides the expansion
$$
\prod_{i=1}^m\sum_{k=1}^{n_i}a_{i,k} = \sum_{\substack{1\leq k_i\leq n_i \\ \forall i=1,\dots,m}}\prod_{i=1}^ma_{i,k_i}
$$
as stated in your question. Therefore, the indexing set for the right hand summation is indeed the set of all $m$-tuples $(k_1,\dots,k_m)$ where $1\leq k_i\leq n_i$ for every $i=1,\dots,m$.

Comment: This is why I use things such as $\Bbbk _i$ to indicate multi-component indexes.  I was reading $k_i$ as an element in an index set.